# substitution in tikz calc

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

In this example

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 1);
  \coordinate (c) at ($(a) + (b)$);
  \coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

one could do away with the `\coordinate(c)` by defining `\coordinate(d)` as

```
\coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!((a) + (b))$);
```

This substitution does not work out:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named (a is known.
```

How to rewrite the expression for `\coordinate(d)` without recurring to `\coordinate(c)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
\coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!($(a) + (b)$)$);
```

The first image below uses

```
  \coordinate (c) at ($(a) + (b)$);
  \coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$);
```

whereas the second uses the calculation mentioned above without the intermediate `(c)` coordinate.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 1);
  
  \coordinate (c) at ($(a) + (b)$);
  \coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$);
    
  \node at (a) {a};
  \node at (b) {b};
  
  \node at (d) {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 1);
  
  \coordinate (d) at ($(a)!0.5!($(a) + (b)$)$);
  
  \node at (a) {a};
  \node at (b) {b};
  
  \node at (d) {d};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A minor remark: since `0.5 a + 0.5 ( a + b ) =a + 0.5 b`, you could also do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 1);
  \coordinate (d) at ($1*(a)+0.5*(b)$);
  \foreach \X in {a,b,d}
  \node at (\X){\X};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That is, `calc` allows you to take arbitrary linear combinations of the coordinates.